# Обратиться к БД пользователя

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Добрый день. Есть два класса: класс контракт - ClassContract и класс, где создается, открывается БД класс - ClassDBHeler. Использую готовую БД, которую положил в папку проекта assets и когда юзер устанавливает приложение соответственно БД копируется к нему и он пользуется приложением.

Вот класс ClassContract

```
public class ClassContract {
    private ClassContract() {
    };

    public static final class ClassEntry implements BaseColumns {
        public final static String TABLE_NAME = "table1";

        public final static String _ID = BaseColumns._ID;
        public final static String COLUMN_WORD = "field1";
        public final static String COLUMN_TRANSLATION = "field2";
        public final static String COLUMN_TYPE = "field3";
        public final static String COLUMN_FAVORITES = "field4";
    }
}
```

Вот класс ClassDBHeler

```
public class ClassDBHeler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/ru.mysite.project1/databases/";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbase.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public SQLiteDatabase database;
    private Context myContext;

    public ClassDBHeler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
        }else{
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch(SQLiteException e){
        }
        if(checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if(database != null)
            database.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Обновил БД и хочу чтобы эти обновления произошли у пользователей. В методе onUpgrade как я могу обращаться к БД, которая уже у пользователей? Как я понял параметр db у onUpgrade это новая БД, а как получить доступ к таблице из старой БД?

Answer (score 2):

db это сущеуствующая база. На телефоне пока что существует только 1 версия. в SQLite нельзя просто так удалить столбец, приходится создавать временную таблицу, перекидывать туда данные, удалять оригинал, создавать его снова с нужной структурой, скидывать в него данные из временной таблицы и удалять временную таблицу.

Смотрите, ваше приложение обновилось. И теперь, при запуске, оно попытается подключиться к БД версии 2, но увидит, что существующая версия = 1 и вызовет метод onUpgrade, дав вам возможность внести необходимые изменения в структуру БД.

А что будет если пользователь поставит новое приложение на свежий смартфон первый раз?

В этом случае приложение также попытается подключиться к БД версии 2. Но т.к. приложение только что установлено, то БД еще не существует. Приложение создаст БД и присвоит ей версию номер 2, т.к. оно умеет работать именно с такой версией. При создании будет вызван метод onCreate в DBHelper.

Вот пример обновления из [уроков](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/79-urok-39-onupgrade-obnovljaem-bd-v-sqlite.html)

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  Log.d(LOG_TAG, " --- onUpgrade database from " + oldVersion
      + " to " + newVersion + " version --- ");

  if (oldVersion == 1 && newVersion == 2) {

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    // данные для таблицы должностей
    int[] position_id = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    String[] position_name = { "Директор", "Программер",
        "Бухгалтер", "Охранник" };
    int[] position_salary = { 15000, 13000, 10000, 8000 };

    db.beginTransaction();
    try {
      // создаем таблицу должностей
      db.execSQL("create table position ("
          + "id integer primary key,"
          + "name text, salary integer);");

      // заполняем ее
      for (int i = 0; i < position_id.length; i++) {
        cv.clear();
        cv.put("id", position_id[i]);
        cv.put("name", position_name[i]);
        cv.put("salary", position_salary[i]);
        db.insert("position", null, cv);
      }

      db.execSQL("alter table people add column posid integer;");

      for (int i = 0; i < position_id.length; i++) {
        cv.clear();
        cv.put("posid", position_id[i]);
        db.update("people", cv, "position = ?",
            new String[] { position_name[i] });
      }

      db.execSQL("create temporary table people_tmp ("
          + "id integer, name text, position text, posid integer);");

      db.execSQL("insert into people_tmp select id, name, position, posid from people;");
      db.execSQL("drop table people;");

      db.execSQL("create table people ("
          + "id integer primary key autoincrement,"
          + "name text, posid integer);");

      db.execSQL("insert into people select id, name, posid from people_tmp;");
      db.execSQL("drop table people_tmp;");

      db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
      db.endTransaction();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Я читал этот урок. Но я не могу понять одну вещь. Если в методе onUpgrade() db это существующая БД которая у пользователя, то как обратиться к БД новой версии? Мне нужно следующее сделать. записи из БД пользователя оставить как есть, но добавить к ним новые записи из новой версии БД. И мне нужно как-то обращаться к новой версии БД и к старой версии БД. Как это делается?

Comment: К новой версии вы не можете обратиться, её ещё не существует. Она появится только после того, как отработает метод onUpgrade, который и обновит старую базу до новой. А в этом методе вы, сосбтвенно, и напишите, что нужно сдлеать, чтобы из старой получилась новая база.

Comment: В этом то и проблема, что я не знаю что в этом методе написать, чтобы старые записи у пользователей не изменились и добавились новые ((

Comment: есть какой-нибудь метод, который вызывается до onUpgrade? Чтобы в нем сохранить данные из старой версии БД?

Comment: Нашел метод onConfigure() через него смог до вызова onUpgrade() вытащить данные в курсор. Но в документации написано что его следует применять только для настройки параметров подключения и т.д. Если для получения в курсор данных из старой БД использовать ничего страшного?

Comment: Да, без проблем. Пока вы не грохнете старую базу, она полностью доступна.